# How do I enable WebGL support on an Intel NM10?

Tags: intel-graphics, 3d, webgl

I'm trying to use webgl on the last version of Chrome and Firefox but both say:

```
Sorry, Your Browser doesn't support WebGL!
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation N10 Family DMI Bridge
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller
```

glxgears:

```
296 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.153 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.846 FPS
```

I'm at ubuntu 12.04 64. What should I install to get this working?

Comment: Please give the exact Chrome / Chromium version, I know you said latest but it's good to check, as there are different update paths and there is the developer version etc.

Comment: Have you tried Ubuntu 13 on live cd or something?

Answer (score 0):

Although I am strugling myself to get WebGL working, I am almost certain that the 64-bit version of your OS does not help. My suggestion is to use Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit. Let me know your progress.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/299345/how-to-enable-webgl-in-chrome-on-ubuntu/299346#299346