# How To Enable WebGL In Chrome On Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

```
chrome://gpu/
```

[image]

And http://webglreport.com/

[image]

```
 google-chrome --version
 Google Chrome 27.0.1453.93
```

http://www.chromeexperiments.com/webgl

[image]

> How To Enable WebGL In Chrome On Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

> For WebGL to work in Google Chrome (and Chromium), Here are the steps to enable WebGL in Google Chrome.

Step 1: Open Google Chrome

Step 2: Type `chrome://flags` in the address bar

Step 3: Press `Ctrl + f` and type ” `Rendering list` “, “Override software rendering list” 
should come up, Now click on Enable and restart the browser.

Step 4: Completely kill Chrome: Type `killall chrome` into a console.

Step 5: Go to `chrome://settings` and enable `Use hardware acceleration when available`. By default it is off since version 43.
[image]

Step 6: Start Chrome

[image]

> Now check      `chrome://gpu/`

[image]

> http://webglreport.com/

[image]

[Source](http://prasopensource.wordpress.com/2012/08/05/how-to-enable-webgl-in-google-chrome-browser-in-gnulinux/)

Comment: Now I have YouTube in HTML5 players with nice performance!

Comment: Why is this not enabled by default???

Comment: @Konstantin Thats a good question, I will do some research on it.

Comment: Hint: in Ubuntu for sure (windows also most likely) you will need to be sure to kill the background threads (chrome) as well before the changes will take effect.

Comment: Nice pointed, Lance. And this is how you kill all chrome instances: ps aux | grep chrome | awk ' { print $2 } ' | xargs kill -9

Comment: +1 Do you know if there is direct link to enable it, without Ctrl+F and all other steps. Or how to enable it from Javascript?

Comment: @Kostanos no i do not know abot that...thats the easiest way ...

Comment: for some reason this does not help me to enable webgl in Chrome 37.0.2062.94 (64-bit) under ubuntu *(

Comment: Somehow this didnt work for me either on ub14.10 with chrome Version 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit)

Comment: @PeterRaeves check dmesg, i think there was an bug in 14.10 that does not.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 15.04, Chromium, NVIDIA GeForce GT 610. Latest aviable drivers(356.49). However, WebGL doesn't work even after doing this. How and why?

Comment: Probably old by now, but all this plus driver installation etc. didn't work for me either, until I realized there is a simple setting in  "chrome://settings , advanced settings, Use hardware acceleration when available". This was disabled by default. Enabling it did the trick for me.

Answer (score 10):

If you still don't get any results, check if hardware-acceleration is enabled in Chromium settings, Google tends to disable this setting by default since version 43. In this case that was the problem for me after I updated GPU drivers, overrode the GPU blacklist, and so and so.

Comment: Same here. I thought I was seeing some terrible bug but didn't realize chrome://settings -> Show advanced settings... -> Use hardware acceleration when available somehow got disabled. I flipped it on, restarted the browser, and everything works.

Comment: Disabling hardware-acceleration worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too old your video driver or not installed properly.

**I had same problem too, but this solution fixed my problem without overrides!**

1. **To add PPA for Ubuntu 14.04 / 13.10 / 13.04 / 12.10**

   Ubuntu 14.04 / 13.10 / 13.04 / 12.10 users, Run the following command in the terminal and type the password for the user when prompted.  Others use the Ubuntu-X PPA.

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
   ```
2. **To add PPA for Ubuntu 12.04 / 11.10 / 11.04 / 10.04**

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
   ```

   After adding the PPA, update your system repository.
3. **To Update**

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   Now install the NVIDIA GeForce graphics driver 304.108 in your system, as you install other packages by using apt-get.
4. **To Install**

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
   ```

   Above command will install the driver.

---

Source: http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-nvidia-geforce-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04-using-ppa/

Comment: I's using this solution on my desktop for a week, but my Chrome sometimes eat all CPU (the "GPU process" task). - I have Ubuntu Trusty with "GeForce 8400 GS Rev. 2" - I can not found solution for this side effect, only I have a workaround: Turn on "Disable accelerated 2D canvas" option in chrome://flags/ ... Grrr

Answer (score 2):

using chromium  Version 49.0.2623.108 on Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit).

What we need to activate is  `#ignore-gpu-blacklist`

It's the first line in `chrome://flags/`

Hope it can help,

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue that WebGL was reported as unavailable [after switching from the proprietary Nvidia to the nouveau drivers](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660493#c8), a change which does not seem to have been picked up in the chromium GPU config of my profile. The fix is running `chromium-browser --single-process` *once* to reset the GPU configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried the things posted above and it is still not working, try using different drivers. Go to Software And Updates and there select Additional Drivers. Then select either the middle option or the last one (either Proprietary Binary or Nuveau). In my case I selected Proprietary Binary, but it got reverted to Nuveau and now I have WebGL enabled..

Answer (score 0):

To have it working again I've had to upgrade mesa drivers.

What needed to be done on `Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS` in my case:

1. In [chrome://flags](https://chrome://flags) `Override software rendering list` -> `ENABLED`
2. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa` to add the PPA
3. `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` to update and upgrade
4. reboot
5. Check that `Use hardware acceleration when available` is `ENABLED` in [chrome://settings/system](https://chrome://settings/system)

DEBUG TOOLS:

1. [chrome://gpu](https://chrome://gpu)
2. https://webglreport.com/?v=2 - you should see `Major Performance Caveat:`**`No`**

NOTES:

1. I'm on `Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS`
2. using `Chrome Version 120.0.6099.71 (Official Build) (64-bit)`
3. I've got `Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G4` (`lspci| grep VGA`)