# Why do I need to use lite mode in the new Google Maps? (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, opengl, google-maps

I was wondering if I could use the new Google Maps. I have latest stable Chrome and Ubuntu 13.04. I am currently told that I must use lite mode. Under Chrome in Windows 8 on the same machine it works perfectly.

Comment: What graphics chip/card do you use?

Comment: Does Firefox work?

Comment: At what point are you told that you must use lite mode?

Answer (score 6):

## Disclaimer: This is not supported by Google

Google Chrome disables hardware acceleration on many GPUs by default in Linux. To check if your GPU is disabled, open `chrome://gpu/` inside Chrome. Mine looks like this by default:

[image: GPU Disabled]

---

To forcefully enable hardware acceleration, open the `chrome://flags/` page.
Search for the *Override Software Rendering list* option and click *Enable*. It looks like this:
[image: Flags]

---

Restart Chrome. Check the `chrome://gpu/` page again. It should say everything is enabled now, like this:
[image: GPU Enabled]

---

Now try out the New Google Maps and see if it works. I don't have an invite, so I can't check >.>

**Be warned this may make your browser crash-prone!**

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/299345/how-to-enable-webgl-in-chrome-on-ubuntu/299346#299346

Comment: Whuddya know, our pictures even look similar :-P.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Had to disable though because of crashes.

Comment: My recommendation: Try Firefox. That may work better.