# video drivers installed, but no WebGL or OpenGL acceleration working

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, intel, gpu-driver

I have a Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition with 14.04 (my first serious go with linux outside of a server) and oem video drivers installed, but nothing requiring 3d acceleration is working.

`lspci | grep VGA` gives me:

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)`

and `lshw -c video` outputs

```
  *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:63 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

`modinfo i915` gives me this

`filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-51-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    Intel Graphics
author:         Tungsten Graphics, Inc.
license:        GPL and additional rights
srcversion:     EAE574025ED8FCDDFFC9401
... deleted for brevity ...
depends:        drm_kms_helper,drm,video,i2c-algo-bit
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-51-generic SMP mod_unload modversions`

I enabled WebGL in Chrome as posted in [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299345/how-to-enable-webgl-in-chrome-on-ubuntu) and I get a false positive that everything is working in `chrome://gpu`

`Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Hardware accelerated
Flash: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Hardware accelerated
Compositing: Hardware accelerated
Multiple Raster Threads: Enabled
Rasterization: Hardware accelerated
Threaded Rasterization: Enabled
Video Decode: Hardware accelerated
Video Encode: Hardware accelerated
WebGL: Hardware accelerated`

Any guidance would be much appreciated for an ubuntu n00b.

Comment: Just to clarify, when I go to any page with WebGL, the detection fails. So [in the three.js examples](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_cloth) I get the "your browser does not support WebGL"

Comment: I would try another webgl site like https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/demos/tag/tech:webgl or https://www.chromeexperiments.com/webgl because the site you gave does not even resolv here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. Upgrading the Intel graphics driver fixed this issue (among other things):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then reboot.

You can read [detailed explanations on my blog](http://blogs.aerys.in/jeanmarc-leroux/2015/05/10/xps13-developer-edition-updating-the-graphics-driver/).

Regards,

Comment: What is the point of upgrading ALL packages, the upgrade specific?

Comment: Another way to get up to date graphic drivers is to use **ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers**. This will not update X that it's advantage. Only graphic drivers.

Comment: You're right, using the oibaf PPA does the trick: I've updated my answer and the blog post. Thank you.

Comment: This rendered all gnome apps completely black. Downgraded and removed the PPA again.

Comment: I had same poor result as kelunik. Gnome windows black. Didn't solve my opengl problem, just caused more problems. Ubuntu 16.04