# WebGL not aviable Chromium

Tags: nvidia, chromium, webgl

This is a problem I recently encountered when I was trying to upload a model to Sketchfab. It shown that WebGL in not supported. I opened `chrome://flags` and enabled `override rendering list`. However, even doing that didn't resolve much. I was able to see primitive preview of model in sketchfab(but not original) and 3D settings still weren't aviable. So here are some screenshots.

Version 43.0.2357.81 Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit)

WebGL report:
[image]

Full resolution:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWvA1.png

`chrome://gpu`:
[image]

Full resolution:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0P8E.png

Nvidia Information:
[image]

Full resolution:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYkDJ.png

I hope that someone can find a solution for this!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Enable WebGL In Chrome On Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/299345/how-to-enable-webgl-in-chrome-on-ubuntu)

Comment: No, Tim, as I checked that thread already and I have different problem.

Comment: What's the different problem?

Comment: As that what is told there doesn't fix my problem. And in second image `Problems Detected` there is something I am not sure about, but may answer it. And I didn't find any GPU releated setting in `chrome://settings`.

Comment: Have you installed nvidia drivers?

Comment: I posted 3rd image showing that and I also told: 356.49. By the way, tested it in Firefox and it works out there.

Comment: You didn't say the version before. I can just see in the image. I'm not sure, I'll ping fabby to see if he knows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is duplicate of [WebGL doesn't work in Chromium on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636322/webgl-doesnt-work-in-chromium-on-ubuntu) question as @Tim noted, here is my answer on it:

The ubuntu maintainer of Chromium has deliberately disabled GPU acceleration in the ubuntu build in Chromium 43.
Here is corresponding bugreport: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1463598

To workaround this issue you can downgrade to a previous version of Chromium (I have installed 41.0.2272.76-0 from Vivid).

Comment: OK! Will it be fixed in next release? And how do I downgrade Chromium version?

Comment: There is not information about when fix will arrive in bugreport yet. You  should be able to downgrade using `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser=41.0.2272.76-0ubuntu1.1134` on Ubuntu 15.04, but I would not recommend using older version of Chromium for everyday browsing due to security issues, that old Chromium can have.

Comment: Basicly- if I currently need WebGL, I use Firefox?

Comment: @AdriansNetlis yes, you can use Firefox if you need WebGL. I'm using Firefox for general browsing and it supports WebGL. I use Chromium only for web-development testing, so it's not a problem for me to run potentially vulnerable old version of Chromium for my local web pages.