# WebGL doesn't work in Chromium on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, webgl

I've realized that I can't see graphics in Chromium 43.0.2357.81 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit), such as `plot x²+y²` in Google.

I've tried several things but nothing seems to fix the problem.

A capture of the "chrome://gpu" is shown under these lines:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByVNpBZ4ijQAQzlJaHdCTi1kXzQ/view?usp=sharing

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe this post could help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/299345/how-to-enable-webgl-in-chrome-on-ubuntu

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D|Display' -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 2):

Here is bugreport of the bug that you have encoutered: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1463598

The ubuntu maintainer of Chromium has deliberately disabled GPU acceleration in the ubuntu build in Chromium 43, see bugreports comments for details.

To workaround this issue you can downgrade to a previous version of Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and have found a solution. Just uninstall chromium completely and reinstall it. I have mentioned the details to do the same in my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870952/webgl-unavailable-on-chromium-but-works-well-on-google-chrome). I hope this helps you. Also, don't forget to enable **Use Hardware Acceleration whenever possible** in the settings and *no need* to set any flags (chrome://flags) . All should be at their default.