# Webgl unavailable on Chromium but works well on Google Chrome

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, chromium

I use Tinkercad for my project work. On Windows 8.1, I had no issues in accessing the site from Chromium. On the other hand, Chromium on my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop, doesn't support the site. I tried out this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299345/how-to-enable-webgl-in-chrome-on-ubuntu), but in vain.

I have also installed Google Chrome and things work fine from there. No issues at all...

I performed some tests on chromium and got the following results.
[image]

and also,

[image]

The **chrome://gpu** lists the following lines.
[image]

About Chromium:
*Version 55.0.2883.87 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution to my problem. As I mentioned that I have installed both, Chromium as well as Chrome, I checked the chrome://flash page.
It mentioned Nvidia as Driver vendor, GL_VENDOR, GL_RENDERER for Chromium.
And for Chrome it mentions:

**Driver vendor Mesa

Driver version  11.2.2

GL_VENDOR   Intel Open Source Technology Center

GL_RENDERER Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile

GL_VERSION  3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.2.2**

I had installed Chromium when I had Nvidia Graphics Driver. But then I removed it as it caused issues. So, the Chromium was unable to locate it.

I simply uninstalled Chromium using the following commands and reinstalled it. Things are working perfectly now.

sudo apt remove chromium-browser
rm -rf ~/.cache/chromium
rm -rf ~/.config/chromium
sudo rm -rf /etc/chromium-browser

The chrome://gpu/ page shows the following output.

[image]