# Ubuntu 23.04 keeps crashing after reopening lid/login

Tags: 23.04

The laptop works great with minimal issues. But when I close the lid to suspend the system and reopen it again, it crashes by logging me in and out repeatedly while flickering the black screen. Restarting the laptop solves the issue, but it's unreasonable to go on without being able to close the lid.

Comment: Do you have "swap" space?  The terminal command `free` will tell you. Read `man mkswap swapon fstab fallocate` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: @waltinator yes. I have 16GB RAM and a swap space as well.

Answer (score 0):

It was a hardware issue. My laptop is Razor Blade. I found [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RazerBlade) about my laptop's common issues with ubuntu. The solution was:

1. Edit the default grub config:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

2. Add `button.lid_init_state=open` to the end of the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` option, like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash button.lid_init_state=open"
```

3. Make changes permanent:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then restart.

Other things I've tried:

- [Make swap area](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-22-04)
- [turn acpi off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting)
- [all solutions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009387/laptop-doesnt-suspend-properly-on-closing-lid)
- changing graphics driver
- reinstalling graphics drivers
- [switch from gdm3 to lightdm](https://%20https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163402/ubuntu-18-04-crashes-freezes-after-sleep-suspend)
- [disable nvidia hibernate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403741/ubuntu-22-04-cant-suspend)
- [switch GPU from nvidia to intel and vice versa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384110/what-gpu-is-active-and-how-to-switch-between-them)